# Only one node of a Kafka Connect cluster responds to REST API requests

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I am running a Kafka Connect cluster on separate host machines, and I am seeing behavior of only one of those nodes responding to REST API requests (specifically: POST, PUT, or DELETE requests).  I can reliably swap the node which responds to API requests by shutting one down, and issuing a write command to the other live node.

Here is my docker-compose worker config:

```
version: '2'
services:
  connect:
    image: debezium/connect:1.1.0.Final
    ports:
     - 8083:8083
    volumes:
     - /etc/kafka/secrets:/etc/kafka/secrets
    environment:
     - BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS=my.region.aws.confluent.cloud:9092
     - GROUP_ID=debezium-postgres
     - CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC=dbz_pg_connect_configs
     - OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC=dbz_pg_connect_offsets
     - STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC=dbz_pg_connect_statuses
     - CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR=3
     - CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR=3
     - CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR=3
     - OFFSET_FLUSH_INTERVAL_MS=8000
     - OFFSET_FLUSH_TIMEOUT_MS=60000
     - CONNECT_SECURITY_PROTOCOL=SASL_SSL
     - CONNECT_SASL_MECHANISM=PLAIN
     - CONNECT_SASL_JAAS_CONFIG=org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username="<user>" password="<pass>";
     - CONNECT_PRODUCER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL=SASL_SSL
     - CONNECT_PRODUCER_SASL_JAAS_CONFIG=org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username="<user>" password="<pass>";
     - CONNECT_PRODUCER_SASL_MECHANISM=PLAIN
     - CONNECT_CONSUMER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL=SASL_SSL
     - CONNECT_CONSUMER_SASL_JAAS_CONFIG=org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username="<user>" password="<pass>";
     - CONNECT_CONSUMER_SASL_MECHANISM=PLAIN
```

I can reproduce this with both a Debezium Postgres connector and a Kafka Snowflake connector.  So I believe the issue is with the Kafka Connect REST API itself, not any specific connector library.

According to the [docs](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/references/restapi.html):

> By default this service runs on port 8083. When executed in distributed mode, the REST API will be the primary interface to the cluster. **You can make requests to any cluster member**; the REST API automatically forwards requests if required.

Here is my setup:

- 2 unique hosts
- 2 dockerized containers running Kafka Connect (the image is actually debezium/connect:1.1.0.Final)
- Both are running the REST service on port 8083.  There is no indication in the docs that this is a problem when the containers are on different hosts

The behavior I see is this:

- GET requests work to both nodes always under all circumstances
- POST/PUT/DELETE requests work on the first node to accept one of these calls.  After that point, only that node responds to POST/PUT/DELETE.

The other node responds with:

```
HTTP/1.1 100 Continue

HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Date: Fri, 24 Apr 2020 17:59:55 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 120
Server: Jetty(9.4.20.v20190813)

{"error_code":500,"message":"IO Error trying to forward REST request: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Connect Timeout"}
```

EDIT: Here are the Kafka Connect Logs:

```
Apr 24 14:11:14 node01 docker-compose[57276]: #033[36mconnect_1  |#033[0m 2020-04-24 19:11:14,934 ERROR  ||  IO error forwarding REST request:    [org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.RestClient]
Apr 24 14:11:14 node01 docker-compose[57276]: #033[36mconnect_1  |#033[0m java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Connect Timeout
Apr 24 14:11:14 node01 docker-compose[57276]: #033[36mconnect_1  |#033[0m #011at org.eclipse.jetty.client.util.FutureResponseListener.getResult(FutureResponseListener.java:118)
Apr 24 14:11:14 node01 docker-compose[57276]: #033[36mconnect_1  |#033[0m #011at org.eclipse.jetty.client.util.FutureResponseListener.get(FutureResponseListener.java:101)
Apr 24 14:11:14 node01 docker-compose[57276]: #033[36mconnect_1  |#033[0m #011at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpRequest.send(HttpRequest.java:685)
Apr 24 14:11:14 node01 docker-compose[57276]: #033[36mconnect_1  |#033[0m #011at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.RestClient.httpRequest(RestClient.java:125)
Apr 24 14:11:14 node01 docker-compose[57276]: #033[36mconnect_1  |#033[0m #011at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.RestClient.httpRequest(RestClient.java:65)
Apr 24 14:11:14 node01 docker-compose[57276]: #033[36mconnect_1  |#033[0m #011at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.resources.ConnectorsResource.completeOrForwardRequest(ConnectorsResource.java:315)
Apr 24 14:11:14 node01 docker-compose[57276]: #033[36mconnect_1  |#033[0m #011at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.resources.ConnectorsResource.createConnector(ConnectorsResource.java:143)
Apr 24 14:11:14 node01 docker-compose[57276]: #033[36mconnect_1  |#033[0m #011at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
Apr 24 14:11:14 node01 docker-compose[57276]: #033[36mconnect_1  |#033[0m #011at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
Apr 24 14:11:14 node01 docker-compose[57276]: #033[36mconnect_1  |#033[0m #011at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
Apr 24 14:11:14 node01 docker-compose[57276]: #033[36mconnect_1  |#033[0m #011at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
Apr 24 14:11:14 node01 docker-compose[57276]: #033[36mconnect_1  |#033[0m #011at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.lambda$static$0(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:52)
Apr 24 14:11:14 node01 docker-compose[57276]: #033[36mconnect_1  |#033[0m #011at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:124)
Apr 24 14:11:14 node01 docker-compose[57276]: #033[36mconnect_1  |#033[0m #011at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:167)
Apr 24 14:11:14 node01 docker-compose[57276]: #033[36mconnect_1  |#033[0m #011at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:176)
Apr 24 14:11:14 node01 docker-compose[57276]: #033[36mconnect_1  |#033[0m #011at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:79)
Apr 24 14:11:14 node01 docker-compose[57276]: #033[36mconnect_1  |#033[0m #011at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:469)
Apr 24 14:11:14 node01 docker-compose[57276]: #033[36mconnect_1  |#033[0m #011at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:391)
Apr 24 14:11:14 node01 docker-compose[57276]: #033[36mconnect_1  |#033[0m #011at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:80)
Apr 24 14:11:14 node01 docker-compose[57276]: #033[36mconnect_1  |#033[0m #011at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:253)
Apr 24 14:11:14 node01 docker-compose[57276]: #033[36mconnect_1  |#033[0m #011at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:248)
Apr 24 14:11:14 node01 docker-compose[57276]: #033[36mconnect_1  |#033[0m #011at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:244)
Apr 24 14:11:14 node01 docker-compose[57276]: #033[36mconnect_1  |#033[0m #011at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:292)
Apr 24 14:11:14 node01 docker-compose[57276]: #033[36mconnect_1  |#033[0m #011at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:274)
Apr 24 14:11:14 node01 docker-compose[57276]: #033[36mconnect_1  |#033[0m #011at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:244)
Apr 24 14:11:14 node01 docker-compose[57276]: #033[36mconnect_1  |#033[0m #011at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:265)
Apr 24 14:11:14 node01 docker-compose[57276]: #033[36mconnect_1  |#033[0m #011at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:232)
Apr 24 14:11:14 node01 docker-compose[57276]: #033[36mconnect_1  |#033[0m #011at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:679)
Apr 24 14:11:14 node01 docker-compose[57276]: #033[36mconnect_1  |#033[0m #011at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:392)
Apr 24 14:11:14 node01 docker-compose[57276]: #033[36mconnect_1  |#033[0m #011at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:346)
Apr 24 14:11:14 node01 docker-compose[57276]: #033[36mconnect_1  |#033[0m #011at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:365)
Apr 24 14:11:14 node01 docker-compose[57276]: #033[36mconnect_1  |#033[0m #011at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:318)
Apr 24 14:11:14 node01 docker-compose[57276]: #033[36mconnect_1  |#033[0m #011at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:205)
Apr 24 14:11:14 node01 docker-compose[57276]: #033[36mconnect_1  |#033[0m #011at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:852)
Apr 24 14:11:14 node01 docker-compose[57276]: #033[36mconnect_1  |#033[0m #011at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:544)
Apr 24 14:11:14 node01 docker-compose[57276]: #033[36mconnect_1  |#033[0m #011at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233)
Apr 24 14:11:14 node01 docker-compose[57276]: #033[36mconnect_1  |#033[0m #011at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1581)
Apr 24 14:11:14 node01 docker-compose[57276]: #033[36mconnect_1  |#033[0m #011at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233)
Apr 24 14:11:14 node01 docker-compose[57276]: #033[36mconnect_1  |#033[0m #011at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1307)
Apr 24 14:11:14 node01 docker-compose[57276]: #033[36mconnect_1  |#033[0m #011at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:188)
Apr 24 14:11:14 node01 docker-compose[57276]: #033[36mconnect_1  |#033[0m #011at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:482)
Apr 24 14:11:14 node01 docker-compose[57276]: #033[36mconnect_1  |#033[0m #011at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1549)
Apr 24 14:11:14 node01 docker-compose[57276]: #033[36mconnect_1  |#033[0m #011at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:186)
Apr 24 14:11:14 node01 docker-compose[57276]: #033[36mconnect_1  |#033[0m #011at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1204)
Apr 24 14:11:14 node01 docker-compose[57276]: #033[36mconnect_1  |#033[0m #011at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
Apr 24 14:11:14 node01 docker-compose[57276]: #033[36mconnect_1  |#033[0m #011at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:221)
Apr 24 14:11:14 node01 docker-compose[57276]: #033[36mconnect_1  |#033[0m #011at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.StatisticsHandler.handle(StatisticsHandler.java:173)
Apr 24 14:11:14 node01 docker-compose[57276]: #033[36mconnect_1  |#033[0m #011at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
Apr 24 14:11:14 node01 docker-compose[57276]: #033[36mconnect_1  |#033[0m #011at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:494)
Apr 24 14:11:14 node01 docker-compose[57276]: #033[36mconnect_1  |#033[0m #011at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:374)
Apr 24 14:11:14 node01 docker-compose[57276]: #033[36mconnect_1  |#033[0m #011at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:268)
Apr 24 14:11:14 node01 docker-compose[57276]: #033[36mconnect_1  |#033[0m #011at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311)
Apr 24 14:11:14 node01 docker-compose[57276]: #033[36mconnect_1  |#033[0m #011at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
Apr 24 14:11:14 node01 docker-compose[57276]: #033[36mconnect_1  |#033[0m #011at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:117)
Apr 24 14:11:14 node01 docker-compose[57276]: #033[36mconnect_1  |#033[0m #011at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:336)
Apr 24 14:11:14 node01 docker-compose[57276]: #033[36mconnect_1  |#033[0m #011at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:313)
Apr 24 14:11:14 node01 docker-compose[57276]: #033[36mconnect_1  |#033[0m #011at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:171)
Apr 24 14:11:14 node01 docker-compose[57276]: #033[36mconnect_1  |#033[0m #011at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:129)
Apr 24 14:11:14 node01 docker-compose[57276]: #033[36mconnect_1  |#033[0m #011at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:367)
Apr 24 14:11:14 node01 docker-compose[57276]: #033[36mconnect_1  |#033[0m #011at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:782)
Apr 24 14:11:14 node01 docker-compose[57276]: #033[36mconnect_1  |#033[0m #011at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:918)
Apr 24 14:11:14 node01 docker-compose[57276]: #033[36mconnect_1  |#033[0m #011at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Apr 24 14:11:14 node01 docker-compose[57276]: #033[36mconnect_1  |#033[0m Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Connect Timeout
Apr 24 14:11:14 node01 docker-compose[57276]: #033[36mconnect_1  |#033[0m #011at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$Connect.run(ManagedSelector.java:802)
Apr 24 14:11:14 node01 docker-compose[57276]: #033[36mconnect_1  |#033[0m #011at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
Apr 24 14:11:14 node01 docker-compose[57276]: #033[36mconnect_1  |#033[0m #011at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
Apr 24 14:11:14 node01 docker-compose[57276]: #033[36mconnect_1  |#033[0m #011at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)
Apr 24 14:11:14 node01 docker-compose[57276]: #033[36mconnect_1  |#033[0m #011at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
Apr 24 14:11:14 node01 docker-compose[57276]: #033[36mconnect_1  |#033[0m #011at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
Apr 24 14:11:14 node01 docker-compose[57276]: #033[36mconnect_1  |#033[0m #011... 1 more
```

EDIT: From what I have learned since originally posting this question, it is clear this is not a bug or undocumented behavior, but has everything to do with docker networking and networking in general between the containers and separate host machines.  I am still unclear, however, as to how to configure this correctly, even on a one-time basis.  We are using nginx and we have an F5 load balancer in front of the 2 nodes.  I am able to ping the other host itself from either container, so the hosts can at least talk to each other.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the worker configuration for your two workers please

Answer (score 1):

It is documented... There is only one leader that forwards requests to the underlying config/status topic. Similar to how there is only one leader topic-partition for any replica.

Nothing is a bug unless you find an open JIRA for it or tried to configure each property related to your problem.

In particular, seems like you didn't set `rest.advertised.listener` ([or the advertised host names](https://rmoff.net/2019/11/22/common-mistakes-made-when-configuring-multiple-kafka-connect-workers/)) to allow for each server to broadcast themselves to one another

Comment: The whole reason for my question is that I believe the docs are quite sparse to anyone but an expert in both docker and kafka connect.  In particular, there is little if any discussion anywhere I can find on containerized kafka connect clusters running on different host machines.  But your answer is helpful along with https://rmoff.net/2019/11/22/common-mistakes-made-when-configuring-multiple-kafka-connect-workers/ in finally getting a complete answer to my question.  So thank you.

Comment: Docker just adds a network layer. It's your network that needs configured correctly (note that the Kafka Operators and Helm Charts do this for you), and Apache Kafka project has no overlap with Docker, so "sparse" is probably not the word I would use. And like I said, Kubernetes (via Operators or Helm) is _probably_ the closest "public" example you'll find running containers on different hosts (although I do it on Mesos and Nomad internally).

Comment: I agree with your assessment.  I have seen via some reading that indeed something like Kubernetes would be a solution.  But I am also interested in how I could get each rest.advertised.host.name accessible by the other workers without a full orchestration platform.  What I'd like to do is massage my question and make this a more clear and helpful question/answer once said and done.  Currently for example one is 171.15.0.2, the other is 171.28.0.2, and they cannot reach each other.

Comment: Don't use IPs. Use service name links https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/

Comment: I don't think I can use links, because the containers are on separate hosts.  I think I need to create a swarm: https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/.  This is why I was looking at bypassing the docker network and using IPs - it's a substantial re-architecture for us to deploy a swarm.  The current solution is only temporary until we can move this cluster of containers to kubernetes, which we are not quite ready for.

Comment: If you have a Compose file, using Swarm is not a major migration, (for starters [`version: 2` should be version 3](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-versioning/#version-2x-to-3x)) but yes, you need an overlay network (like [Weave Net](https://www.weave.works/oss/net/))  and no, using IPs is still a bad idea. Alternatively, like I said, use Helm Charts [with Kubernetes](https://k3s.io), or install [Hashicorp Nomad](https://www.nomadproject.io) ... At the end of the day, you will definitiely need/want a container orchestrator if it isn't Swarm

Comment: In fact , [using Strimzi](https://strimzi.io/quickstarts/) shouldn't take more than 10 minutes to use end-to-end.